# Definition of normal subgroup vs normal operator

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Why is a normal operator defined as T such that $T^*T=TT^*$ rather than as an element in some normal subgroup N, i.e. $N = \{n| n\in G, gng^{-1}\in N\}$. Is the idea that a normal operator is "normal" to its adjoint?

Comment: The two uses of the word "normal" are unrelated. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7389/what-are-the-most-overloaded-words-in-mathematics for more examples of this phenomenon.

Comment: okay. That's what I figured, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This means only that $T^*$ is contained in the centralizer/normalizer of $T$.